# If $M$ is convex, prove that $M^\circ$ and $\bar M$ are convex

Tags: proof-verification, convex-analysis, normed-spaces

> Let $E$ a normed vector space and $M\subseteq E$ a convex set. Then prove that $M^\circ$ and $\bar M$ are convex.

(Here I used $M^\circ$ to denote the interior set of $M$, and $\bar M$ to denote the closure of $M$.)

I would like a verification for this proof. Thank you in advance.

Lets start with the case $M$ convex implies $M^\circ$ is also convex. Suppose that $M^\circ$ is not convex, then for some $x,y\in M^\circ$ the path defined for convexity as

$$f:[0,1]\to E,\quad t\mapsto (1-t)x+ty$$

is not contained in $M^\circ$ (but it is contained in $M$ because $M$ is convex), that is, exists some $t'$ such that $f(t')\notin M^\circ$, i.e. $f(t')$ is not an interior point of $M$, then for any open ball of $f(t')$ there are points that belong to $M^\complement$.

Because $x$ and $y$ are interior points choose some $\epsilon>0$ such that the open balls $\Bbb B(x,\epsilon)$ and $\Bbb B(y,\epsilon)$ are contained in $M^\circ$.

Then we pick some $p\in(\Bbb B(f(t'),\epsilon)\cap M^\complement)$, i.e. some point that is not contained in $M$ and belong to the open ball of $f(t')$ of radius $\epsilon$.

Now set $v:=f(t')-p$. Now observe that the vectors $x-v$ and $y-v$ belong to the respective balls defined above for $x$ and $y$, i.e.

$$\|v\|=\|f(t')-p\|<\epsilon\implies \|x-v\|< \|x\|+\epsilon\implies x-v\in\Bbb B(x,\epsilon)$$

Then the straight path defined between $x-v$ and $y-v$ contains $p$, what not belong to $M$, i.e.

$$g(t')=(1-t')(x-v)+t'(y-v)=(1-t')x+t'y-(1-t')(f(t')-p)-t'(f(t')-p)=p$$

where $f(t')=(1-t')x+t'y$. Then we have a contradiction with the condition of convexity over $M$. Then $M^\circ$ is convex.$\Box$

---

For the case of $\bar M$ we repeat the same technique, i.e. if $\bar M$ is not convex then exists some $x,y\in\bar M\setminus M$ such that for some $t'$ we have that $f(t')$ is not contained in $\bar M$.

Then we choose some $\epsilon>0$ such that $\Bbb B(f(t'),\epsilon)\subset \bar M^\complement$, because $f(t')$ is an interior point of $\bar M^\complement$. Now we pick points $x'\in(\Bbb B(x,\epsilon)\cap M)$ and $y'\in(\Bbb B(y,\epsilon)\cap M)$.

In a similar manner as above we can conclude that the point $g(t')$ defined as

$$g(t')=(1-t')x'+t'y'$$ is contained in the open ball $\Bbb B(f(t'),\epsilon)$, i.e.

$$\|(1-t')x'+t'y'\|=\|(1-t')(x+r)+t'(y+s)\|<\|f(t')\|+\epsilon$$

because $\|s\|,\|r\|<\epsilon$. This contradicts the assumption that $M$ is convex, so $\bar M$ is convex.$\Box$

Comment: You might want to use the word interior in the title, as the notation varies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks good. However it is a little bit complicated than necessary.

For the interior: Let $x,y\in M^\circ$ with $x\ne y$ and $t\in(0,1)$. Then, the mapping, for $u\in E$,
$$ f(u) = (1-t)x + tu $$
is a homeomorphism from $E$ onto $E$, as $t\ne 0$. By convexity of $M$ we also have $f(M) \subseteq M$. Now, let $V\subseteq M$ be an open neighborhood of $y$, then $f(V)$ is an open neighborhood of $f(y)$ and subset of $M$.

For the closure: Let $x,y\in \bar M$ with $x\ne y$ and $t\in(0,1)$. Let $x_\alpha, y_\alpha\in M$ with $(x_\alpha, y_\alpha)\to (x,y)$. Then,
$$ M \ni (1-t) x_\alpha + ty_\alpha \to (1-t)x + ty \in \bar M. $$

Comment: You never use in the first part that $x\in\mathring M$. It is enough that only one point is in the interior.

Comment: @A.G. Yes. It is only for symmetry 

Comment: When you say "homeomorphism" it is a bit unclear between what sets (I guess you mean $M$ and $f(M)$). It is perhaps easier to make $x=0$ by translation and then $f(u)=tu$ becomes just scaling with $tV$ being open neighbourhood of $f(y)$.

Comment: @A.G. Let $a\in E$ then $f((a - (1-t)x)/t) = a$. Notice that $f$ and $f^{-1}$ are continuous.

Comment: @A.G. It was a little bit sloppy... I have added some details.